# (Double) Crystal reflection operators on SSYTs

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, crystals

I am not that familiar with the language of crystals, but this is what I know:

Let $SSYT(\lambda, \mu)$ be the set of semi-standard Young tableaux with shape $\lambda$ and weight $\mu$.

There are crystal operators, $e_i$, $f_i$ that preserves the shape, but converts one box of content $i$ to a box with content $i+1$ (or vice versa for $f_i$). Sometimes, this is not possible, and then these act as zero.

Now, using these crystal operators repeatedly we can construct crystal reflection operators:
$$s_i : SSYT(\lambda, \mu) \to SSYT(\lambda, s_i\mu),$$
thus giving a proof that the Schur polynomials are indeed symmetric.
The $s_i$ are nice, in the sense that they satisfy 
$$s_i^2 = id \qquad s_is_j = s_js_i\; \text{ if }\; |i-j|>1\qquad \text{ and } \; s_is_js_i = s_js_is_j\; \text {  if  } \; i=j+1.$$

These have been studied a lot by Lascoux-Schützenberger, and it is easy to perform the operator $s_i$: Read the SSYT row by row from bottom to top (English notation) and on the subword on the letters $i$ and $i+1$,
we to a type of matching, which determines which letters to fix. The remaining subword is of the form $i^a (i+1)^b$ which is mapped to $i^b (i+1)^a$.

**Question:** Are there similar reflection operators $t_i$ (satisfying the 3 properties above), but preserving both shape and weight?

$$t_i : SSYT(\lambda, \mu) \to SSYT(\lambda, \mu).$$

*This should somehow be related to biwords and behave predictable under RSK.* Finally, I want to apply this in relation to *key polynomials*,
so I would expect $t_i$ to do some type of permutation on the *right key* of the tableau.

Comment: Ah, right, fixed.

Comment: If you are using the same operators I am, they don't obey $s_i s_{i+1} s_i = s_{i+1} s_i s_{i+1}$. Look at the two tableaux of shape $(2,2)$ and content $(1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I suppose not, since $s_i$ fixes both tableaux, for every $i$ in this case. In general, as it is described above, if the number of boxes with content $i$ and content $i+1$ are equinumerous, then $s_i$ acts as identity.

Note: These are NOT the classical Bender-Knuth involutions!

Comment: You're right, I'm confused. Still not sure I believe your claim, but I'll need to think about it better.